# App page posts through app is not showing up on mobile news feed

Tags: facebook, mobile, feed

I am experiencing a quite rare issue. I post on one of my Facebook pages with a granted application. That traffic goes to my website. From one day to the other, the mobile visitors went from 30% to 5%.

I checked my news feed with my iPod and I noticed that my application page posts are not showing up in the mobile version but only in the desktop. However, if I post directly, without my application, in the news feed, I have no problems at all and my posts are visible in mobile Facebook too.

What should I do? Is there any kind of limitation to posting applications?

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it by posting through RSS Graffiti. The only problem is that I can't stop the posting on a hour-like basis. With my cron job, I would post from 6 AM to 23 PM. Now, with RSS Graffiti, all I can do is post every X period of time (every hour in my case).

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~